Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
I tried to install xautodl. Then i got the error:
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
I am using python verion 3.11 and numpy version 1.24.2.
I tried some other version of numpy. But i am getting same error. Downgrading of python version also does not work as it requires administrator permissions.
